# how to show details of user into gridview where 1st girdview contain list of link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I have 2 grid-view on the same page

- 1st contain the link button where text on the link button is the name of the user comes from database to show user specific details.
- 2nd grid-view to show the selected user details

Now when user click on link from first grid-view then it can view the details of that user in second grid-view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"  AllowPaging="True" pagesize ="5"  />
    <br /><b><u>Store Details</u></b><br /><br />
    <asp:DetailsView id="DetailsView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
    DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging ="true" Runat="server" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestingConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="select * from UserDetails" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestingConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="select * from UserDetails WHERE ID=@ID" >
    <SelectParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="ID" ControlID="GridView1" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

By using above code i get what i want but i have one more query i.e. i want to use link button because i also using url rewriting so for that i need to link button for every user so that i can change my url also for that user

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here are two Master/Detail Example with asp.net

http://www.vkinfotek.com/detailsview/gridview-detailsview-master-detail-example.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16779/GridView-DetailsView-Master-Detail-Control

Comment: your links are good but the thing is that i have 10 user and when i click on any of the link from my grid-view it will show details first user only in detailsview

Comment: please provide logic you written in Logic1_Click function

Comment: can i use link button in place of autogeneratedselect link